# Rails - How to order query of sum() and group()?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In our Rails 4.2 app, here is query which does `sum()` and `group()` on `payment` record:

```
Payment.joins(:project, :pr_category).select("sum(payments.amount) as Total, projects.name as Project, definitions.name as Category").group('payments.project_id, payments.pr_category_id').order('payments.project_id')
```

The query does its job creating sum based on project and its category. However we are having hard time to `order it by project_id` (records for one project were scattered). We also tried `order('Project')` to no avail (we did not try to add a `project_id` as an column and try to order on it since we don't need the id). Also tried to put `order` right after `joins`. All these can not change the order of the query.  What's the right way to order a query out of `sum()` and `group()`?

Comment: What SQL did that generate?

Comment: Good thoughts. The records set was premeditated with order by payment.id in previous step. That's why the late order is put behind and does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort outside of ActiveRecord by using `sort_by` of the `Enumerable` mixins:

```
Payment.joins(:project, :pr_category).select("sum(payments.amount) as Total, projects.name as Project, definitions.name as Category, payments.project_id as project_id").group('payments.project_id, payments.pr_category_id').sort_by { |p| c.project_id }
```